# Ping a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Guys i have been having trouble with making one active cell ping and output a result i have code that does a whole column but i want to create a button that does just one selected cell and make it work in the same way please can anybody help me ?
Here is my code that i found on the net im unsure how to modify it for one cell i have tried numerous times without success...

```
    Function GetPingResult(checkip)

   Dim objPing As Object
   Dim STATUS As Object
   Dim Result1 As String

   Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}"). _
       ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & checkip & "'")

   For Each objStatus In objPing
      Select Case objStatus.statuscode
         Case 0: Result1 = "ONLINE"
         Case Else: Result1 = "OFFLINE"
      End Select
      GetPingResult = Result1
   Next

   Set objPing = Nothing

End Function

Sub GetIPStatus()

  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim IPRANGE As Range
  Dim Result As String
  Dim wks As Worksheet


Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set IPRANGE = wks.Range("B3")
Set RngEnd = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, IPRANGE.Column).End(xlUp)
Set IPRANGE = IIf(RngEnd.Row < IPRANGE.Row, IPRANGE, wks.Range(IPRANGE, RngEnd))

  For Each Cell In IPRANGE
    Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
    Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Result
  Next Cell

End Sub
------------------------------------
I tried this:

Sub PingSelectedCell()

Dim Cell As String

ActiveCell.Select
Cell = GetPingResult(ActiveCell.Value)

Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Result

End Sub
```

But it just returns offline constantly what am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Cell = GetPingResult(ActiveCell.Value)
> Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
> ```

You only need one statement instead:

```
Result = GetPingResult(ActiveCell.Value)
```

then afterwards:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so so much that work perfectly!

```
Sub PingSelectedCell()

Dim Cell As String

Result = GetPingResult(ActiveCell.Value)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Result

End Sub
```